# Dual boot manager not displaying XP after i installed Win7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

I'm a Java Student and my Tomcat Server wasnt running properly on my XP OS and since i cant afford buying a new OS for my computer, i had to get one the easy way.

So,I installed an unconventional version of Windows 7 that i found somewhere on the web.

The win 7 works fine but most of my disk space is located in my XP partition so i d'like to go back to XP in order to clean up my disk but i'm afraid i didnt setup the dual boot properly.

Now i cant access the XP part of my computer because XP doesnt showup in the dual boot manager.
It also seem like both OS are running on the same disk partition.

How can i start my computer XP or just get rid of win 7 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 uses a different boot loader which I believe is the source of your problem here.  You'll need to use [BCDEdit](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/modifying-the-windows-7-boot-loader-with-the-boot-configuration-data-editor-tool/1709).  [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserver2008appcompatabilityandcertification/thread/076fcb7b-6575-4f41-963f-4dc84fffdb29/) is also relevant.

Comment: BCDEDIT created and added XP (or any other name of my choice) to the BCD ,which apears in de boot option when i restart my computer. The problem is that when i select this new name, only a black screen apears. meaning, its just an empty name.

Comment: [Do these steps](http://blogs.interfacett.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-windows-xp-using-bcd-boot-configuration-database) work?  Beyond just a name, you need to tell it which partition and where to load out of.