# Windows XP and Windows Server OS

Tags: windows-xp

Suppose you have the following scenario:

You have Windows XP installed on partition `C:`, then you have installed Windows Server on partition `D:`, now at computer start-up we should see two options to select from; either launch the XP OS or the Server OS.

If you have formatted the partition `C:` and reinstalled Windows XP, your computer will automatically start the Windows XP OS, you will not have two options at computer start-up; you have a Windows Server still installed on `D:`, but you can’t launch it.

How can you solve this problem without reinstalling Windows Server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows boot menu doesn't appear when booting](http://superuser.com/questions/501271/windows-boot-menu-doesnt-appear-when-booting), http://superuser.com/questions/99162/reinstalling-the-windows-7-boot-manager?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/563418/dual-boot-manager-not-displaying-xp-after-i-installed-win7, http://superuser.com/questions/305764/how-to-dual-boot-when-windows-xp-was-installed-after-windows-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following article that explains how to edit the boot.ini file via the bootcfg utility.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317521

The `bootcfg` command is a Microsoft Windows Server 2003 utility that modifies the Boot.ini file. This command has a function that can scan your computer's hard disks for Microsoft Windows NT, Microsoft Windows 2000, Microsoft Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003 installations, and then add them to an existing Boot.ini file or rebuild a new Boot.ini file if one does not exist. You can use the `bootcfg`command to add additional Boot.ini file parameters to existing or new entries.

The `bootcfg` command is available in the Windows Server 2003 operating system and in the Recovery Console. This article describes only the options that are available to `bootcfg` while in the Recovery Console. Not all the options that are available in `bootcfg` in the Recovery Console are in the version of Bootcfg.exe that ships with Windows Server 2003. Bootcfg.exe has a different set of commands available. You can start the Recovery Console by using one of the following methods:
Start your computer with the Windows Server 2003 CD-ROM, and then press R to select Recovery Console.
Install the Recovery Console locally by using the Winnt32.exe /cmdcons command. Restart the server, and then select Microsoft Windows Recovery Console on the Startup menu.

**The `bootcfg` Command and Its Uses**

For a list of the available `bootcfg` commands, type `bootcfg`at the Recovery Console command prompt, and then press ENTER.
The `bootcfg /default` command sets the default operating system option on the Startup menu (this command selects the operating system entry automatically).
The `bootcfg /add` command scans the computer for Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, or Windows Server 2003 installations, and then displays the results. From this screen, you can add an installation to the Startup menu.

When you enter this command, you receive a message similar to the following:

> Scanning all disks for Windows Installations.
>
> Please wait, since this may take a while...
>
> The Windows installation scan was successful.
>
> Note: These results are stored statically for this session. If the
>   disk configuration changes during this session, in order to get an
>   updated scan, you must first reboot the machine and then rescan the
>   disks.
>
> Total identified Windows installs: 2
>
> [1]: C:\WINNT [2]: F:\WINDOWS
>
> Select an installation to add:

When you type the number of the installation that you want, a new entry is added to the Startup menu as the default operating system to start.

The `bootcfg /rebuild` command scans your computer for Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, or Windows Server 2003 installations, and then displays the results. From this screen, you can add the detected Windows installations to the Startup menu.

When you enter this command, you receive a message similar to the following:

> The Windows installation scan was successful.
>
> Note: These results are stored statically for this session. If the
>   disk configuration changes during this session, in order to get an
>   updated scan, you must first reboot the machine and then rescan the
>   disks.
>
> Total identified Windows installs: 2
>
> [1]: C:\WINNT Add installation to boot list? (Yes/No/All):

When you type y, and then press ENTER, you receive the following message:
Enter Load Identifier:
Type the description of the installation that you want displayed on the Startup menu. For example, type Microsoft Windows Server 2003, and then press ENTER.

You receive the following message:

> Enter OS Load Options: Type the operating system load options that you
>   want. For example, type /fastdetect, and then press ENTER.

The `bootcfg /scan` command scans your computer for Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003 installations, and then displays the results.

When you enter this command, you receive a message similar to the following:

> The Windows installation scan was successful.
>
> Note: These results are stored statically for this session. If the
>   disk configuration changes during this session, in order to get an
>   updated scan, you must first reboot the machine and then rescan the
>   disks.
>
> Total identified Windows installs: 2
>
> [1]: C:\WINNT [2]: F:\WINDOWS The bootcfg /list command reads the
>   Boot.ini file, and then displays the operating system identifier, the
>   operating system load options, and the operating system location
>   (path). When you enter this command, you receive a message similar to
>   the following: Total entries in boot list: 2
>
> [1]: "Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Enterprise Edition" OS Load
>   Options: /fastdetect OS Location: F:\WINDOWS
>
> [2]: "Microsoft Windows 2000 Server" OS Load Options: /fastdetect OS
>   Location: C:\WINNT

The `bootcfg /ems` command permits redirection in the boot loader, with the configuration specified as port and baud rate. This command is used to start the Headless Administration feature.

NOTE: Headless Administration is the administration of a computer that does not have a physical monitor, keyboard, mouse, or switch box attached.

The following is an example of how you can use this command:

```
bootcfg /ems /port com1 /baud 115200
```

NOTE The `bootcfg /disableems` command turns off the redirection functionality in the boot loader, with the configuration specified as port and baud rate. This command is used to turn off the Headless Administration feature.

You can also modify the Boot.ini file in the Windows Server 2003 graphical user interface (GUI). To do this, use one of the following methods.

**Method 1: Modify Boot.ini in the Startup and Recovery Dialog Box**

1. Click Start > Settings > Control Panel.
2. Double Left Click System.
3. Click the Advanced tab, click Settings under Startup and Recovery, and then click Edit.
4. The Boot.ini file is opened in Notepad.
5. When you finish editing the Boot.ini file, click Save on the File menu, and then quit Notepad.
6. In the Startup and Recovery dialog box, click OK twice.

**Method 2: Modify Boot.ini by using the System Configuration Utility**

1. Click Start > Run.
2. In the Open box, type `msconfig`, and then click OK.
3. In the System Configuration Utility dialog box, click the BOOT.INI tab.

Comment: Why downvote?   This information will resolve his issue and allow him to add the windows server install to the boot selection menu...

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Gotcha.   Will edit post.   Thanks Techie007

Comment: NP, once I see it edited I'll remove my nasty down-vote. ;)

Comment: @techie007 It's been edited.